# Is there something similar to TensorFlow's make_csv_dataset that works with a string variable?

Tags: python, csv, http, tensorflow

I have a simple Jupyter notebook that loads a simple CSV from a HTTP request...

```
import http.client

connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('localhost', 3000, timeout=10)

connection.request("GET", "/")
response = connection.getresponse()
resStr = bytes.decode(response.read(), 'utf-8')

connection.close()
print(resStr)
```

But when I look at the [make_csv_dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) docs it requires a filename. Is there an equivalent that can be used as a var reference?